# Mostrar elementos especificos de objecto con arrays

Tags: php

Estoy intentando imprimir unos datos específicos de un objecto que contiene arrays pero no consigo imprimirlos, si hago un var_dump de este objecto me imprime lo siguiente :

```
object(Hospital)#1 (2) {
  ["doctores"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Doctor)#2 (2) {
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(7) "Doctor1"
      ["pacientes"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(Paciente)#4 (1) {
          ["nombre"]=>
          string(8) "Paciente1"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Doctor)#3 (2) {
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(9) "Doctor2"
      ["pacientes"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(Paciente)#5 (1) {
          ["nombre"]=>
          string(10) "Paciente2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["pacientes"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Paciente)#4 (1) {
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(8) "Paciente1"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Paciente)#5 (1) {
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(10) "Paciente2"
    }
  }
}
```

Me interesa imprimir los datos del array de 'doctores' por ejemplo 'Doctor1,Paciente1' y 'Doctor2,Paciente2' del array de 'pacientes' no me interesa imprimir nada.

Lo estoy intentando de esta manera pero no me imprime nada.

```
 public function imprimirDatos(){

    foreach ($this->hospital as $datos) {
           echo $datos;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dice @Orici, en el contexto actual puedes encontrar el nombre de cada paciente abriendo un segundo bucle dentro del `foreach` que recorre tu array de doctores.

Otra forma de hacerlo sería dotando a la clase `Doctor` de un método que te traiga su lista de pacientes. Si nos atenemos a la lógica, la clase tendría en propiedad un array de elementos de la clase `Paciente` y un método para agregar pacientes.

La ventaja de esto es que, dentro del bucle que lee los datos del doctor puedes invocar al método: `getPatientsByName` y te traerá la lista de pacientes. Otra cosa interesante es que ese método usaría para cada paciente el método `getName` de la clase `Paciente`.

Al manejar una lista de objetos del tipo `Paciente`, podremos obtener así cualquier otra propiedad invocando los métodos de ese objeto. Suponte que se necesite también una lista de las enfermedades del paciente... sería tan simple como agregar un método `getPatientsByDisease`  que leería en `Paciente` la lista de enfermedades que este padece.

Haciendo esto, nos estaríamos moviendo en un escenario real de POO, y estaríamos sacando los grandes provechos que ofrece este tipo de programación.

La clases adaptadas según lo dicho serían algo así... no pongo constructor ni nada, las dejo lo más simples posible:

#### `Doctor`

```
class Doctor {
    private $listPatients=array();
    private $name;
    
    public function setName($name){
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }    
    
    public function addPatient(Paciente $p){
        $this->listPatients[]=$p;
    }
    
    public function getPatientsByName(){
        $patientsName="";
        foreach($this->listPatients as $patient){
            $patientsName.="\t".$patient->getName().PHP_EOL;
        }
        return $patientsName;   
    }
}
```

---

#### `Paciente`

```
class Paciente {
    private $name;
    
    public function setName($name){
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }           
}
```

---

#### Prueba

Ahora podemos trabajar cómodamente con los métodos de nuestros objetos, y no con las propiedades:

```
foreach ($hospital->doctores as $doctor){
    echo "Doctor: {$doctor->getName()}\n";
    echo "Pacientes: \n {$doctor->getPatientsByName()}";
    echo "--------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Salida:

```
Doctor: Galeno
Pacientes:
    Pedro d1
    Juan d1
--------------------------------------
Doctor: Hipócrates
Pacientes:
    María d2
--------------------------------------
```

---

#### Código de ejemplo

Puedes ver una **<kbd>[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/HQBTLC27225)</kbd>** del código completo con los datos que se han usado y hacer pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function imprimirDatos()
{
    // array de doctores para el hospital
    $doctores = $this->hospital->doctores;

    foreach ($doctores as $doctor) {
        $nombre_doctor = $doctor->nombre;

        // array de pacientes para el doctor
        $pacientes = $doctor->pacientes;

        foreach ($pacientes as $paciente) {
            echo $nombre_doctor . ',' . $paciente->nombre . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```